# Is the free() safe in the pop function of this lock free stack?

Tags: c, multithreading, stack, lock-free

I've been studying the lock free stack.
I was reading this [link](https://lumian2015.github.io/lockFreeProgramming/aba-problem.html) and the pop function got me wondering.

According to the link, the pop function is implemented as follows.

```
int lfstack_pop(_Atomic lfstack_t *lfstack)
{
    lfstack_t next, orig = atomic_load(lfstack);

    do{
       if(orig.head == NULL)
       {
            return -1;
       }
       next.head = orig.head->next;
       next.tag = orig.tag+1; //increase the "tag"
    }while(!atomic_compare_exchange_weak(lfstack,&orig,next));

    printf("poping value %d\n",orig.head->data);
    free(orig.head);

    return 0;
}
```

In the above implementation, we are solving the ABA problem by using separate tag information.
So far, so good.

But my question is this.
Is the line `next.head = orig.head->next;` thread-safe?

If the line `next.head = orig.head->next;` resumes in thread 2 after `free(orig.head);` in thread 1, isn't that an error because we're referencing `next` after `orig.head` has been deallocated?

The links I'm looking at don't mention this issue, so I'm wondering if this is safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the line `next.head = orig.head->next;` thread-safe?
>
> If the line `next.head = orig.head->next;` resumes in thread 2 after
> `free(orig.head);` in thread 1, isn't that an error because we're
> referencing next after `orig.head` has been deallocated?

You have identified a *bona fide* flaw in the function.  Good job.

It is indeed possible for two threads executing `lfstack_pop()` concurrently to load the same value into their respective `orig` locals.  Although each thread's `orig` is local to that thread, both `orig.head` pointers point to the same object.  In that case, if one thread proceeds through `free()`ing its `orig.head` before the other thread evaluates `orig.head->next then the second will reap undefined behavior on account of dereferencing an indeterminate pointer value. Nothing in particular prevents that.

Note well that the behavior is still undefined as far as the C language specification is concerned even in the event that in the interim, a new node is allocated at the address to which `orig.head` initially pointed. (This is the case in which the ABA problem arises that the code purports to solve.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!
So to avoid UB in these cases, should I delay the deallocation of the object?

Comment: @tongstar, the problem with deferring deallocation is how to know (in a lock-free way) when it is safe to deallocate.  Possibly you could set up some kind of atomic reference count on the nodes, but I think that would be extremely difficult to do correctly, given that you have to contend not just with other pops, but also with *pushes*.  Linked lists are not well suited in general for lock-free use because many operations on them require reading one value from the list (a `next` pointer, for example) in order to update a different one.

Comment: I think I would be inclined to use an atomic spin-lock, which very well might not satisfy your definition of "lock free".